# How to scale the fill, but not the stroke in Actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Let's say I have a box. The fill is a gradient and the stroke has 1 pixel thickess. How would I resize its fill but keep the stroke thickness intact?

```
private function resizeMovieClip(newWidth:Number, newHeight:Number):void 
{
   this.movieClip.width = newWidth;
   this.movieClip.height = newHeight;
}
```

Basically, I'd like to emulate Javascript's resizing of DOM elements. In JS, resizing a box would never alter its border.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set the scaleMode of the [lineStyle()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#lineStyle%28%29) to [LineScaleMode.NONE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LineScaleMode.html)

```
var sh:Shape = new Shape();
sh.graphics.lineStyle(1.0, 0x000000, 1.0, false, LineScaleMode.NONE);
sh.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1.0);
sh.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
sh.graphics.endFill();

addChild(sh);

sh.scaleX = sh.scaleY = 4.0;
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the `LineScaleMode` in the Flash WYSIWYG IDE? I already have the fill and stroke drawn out there.

Comment: It appears that doing `mc.graphics.lineStyle(...)` on a shape that already exists in the FLA does not work. It only works when you are creating these shapes on-the-fly.

Answer (score 2):

With [9 Scale Slicing](http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/scale9/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your MC is drawn but I would redraw the stroke every time it was resized:

```
private function resizeMovieClip(newWidth:Number, newHeight:Number):void 
{
    this.graphics.clear();

    this.movieClip.width = newWidth;
    this.movieClip.height = newHeight;   

    this.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x000000);
    this.graphics.lineTo(this.width,0);
    this.graphics.lineTo(this.width,this.height);
    this.graphics.lineTo(0,this.height);
    this.graphics.lineTo(0,0);
}
```

**Disclaimer:** Of course this will clear anything else drawn with the graphics API on it before re-drawing the border, and it might not work depending on how your MC is drawn.

Comment: this is not required and is more processor intensive if you're scaling.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, as OP has mentioned, this option can be modified directly in the IDE.

[image: Scale dropdown in Flash]

You will notice that the scaling has changed because the line might become thinner. If this does not happen, click on something else and then back on the line you are modifying. The scaling might have changed back to Normal. It appears that sometimes, changing the scaling doesn't work. If you make the scaling Horizontal or Vertical first, then change it to None, it should work.